# AngularFire should a provider's uid be the same as an anonymous user's uid after they are linked?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to link a provider to an anonymous user. I am able to login both separately.

```
var auth = $firebaseAuth();
auth.$signInAnonymously().then(function(firebaseUser) {...}

$scope.signInWithGoogle = function() {
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

  auth.$signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(function(response) {
      linkCredentials(response.user);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Authententication failed:", error);
    });
}

var linkCredentials = function(credential) {
  if(credential) {
    var credentials = credential;
  }

  firebase.auth().currentUser.link(credentials)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
        console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", firebaseUser);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
    });
}
```

When I linked an account with email and password (i.e `$createUserWithEmailAndPassword`), the `uid` for the *newly* created account was the same as the anonymous account.

Should the Google user's uid be same as the anonymous account after they are linked? or am I confusing things here? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you link a new provider to an existing account, regardless if it is anonymous or not, the same uid should persist. However, if you try to link a provider that is already linked to an existing firebase user with a different uid, you will get an error that the credential is already linked to another account. You seem to be doing it incorrectly above. You are signing in the google user after anonymous user sign in effectively logging out the previous anonymous user. The correct way to do it is as follows:

You first sign in anonymously.

You then call linkWithPopup on the current anonymous user.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the `linkWithPopup()` wasn't available on the `auth` or `$firebaseAuth()` in my case i was able to get it from `auth.$getAuth();` https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/764